# How to create new folders and put a file on it

Tags: file-management

In order to match the criteria of a "coverflow" like soft I have to create a specific folder (named "name_of_the_film") for each film.avi and cover.jpg I have in my film directory :

Today:

```
d:/film/starwars.avi, 
d:/film/starwars2.avi
d:/film/starwars.jpg
d::film/starwars2.jpg
```

Tomorrow:

```
d:/film/starwars
d:/film/starwars/starwars.avi
d:/film/starwars/starwars.jpg 
d:/film/starwars2
d:/film/starwars2/starwars2.avi
d:/film/starwars2/starwars2.jpg
```

Is it possible to do this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any apps which do this, but you can write a short Perl or Python script to do this for you. The following perl script should do what you need:

```
use File::Copy;

my $baseDir = "D:/film/";

opendir my $dir, $baseDir or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir $dir;

foreach my $file (@files)
{
  $fileName = $1 if ($file =~ /^(.*)\.[^\.]+$/i);
  mkdir("$baseDir/$fileName") unless (-d "$baseDir/$fileName");
  move("$baseDir/$file", "$baseDir/$fileName/$file");
}
```

Assuming you have perl installed, save this script as CreateMovieFolders.pl and then run `perl CreateMovieFolders.pl` from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a batch script.

[See here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true) for a list of ways you can mangle for loop variables.